# Этимология слова «Глюк»

Tags: этимология

Как образовалось слово «глюк»? Различные источники утверждают, что оно произошло от слова «галлюцинация», но без дальнейших объяснений, а они так друг на друга не похожи

Comment: Забавно, что в английском есть слово glitch (сбой) и произношение glitches напоминает "глючит", но тем не менее "глючит" не заимствовано из английского языка и этимология у обоих слов разная.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This word and its derivatives (**приглючилось**, **глючный**, **глючить**) originally belongs to slang of the Russian hippies community, which has been established a bit later then in western word, in 70s.

In its first meaning **глюк** was indeed just a shorthand for **галлюцинация** (hallucination) and has been used in context of drug usage.

As for the reasons why exactly this form has been adopted, I guess this word has been widely adopted because it is short, sounds funny to native speaker and at the same time can be easily used to produce new forms (such as mentioned above).

Gradually this word migrated to IT community which (to some extent) overlapped with hippies community. In IT slang this word acquires new meaning close to the word **баг** but not equivalent to it.

Comment: I recall there was another derivative of **галлюцинация** -- **галюник** (usually pl. -- **галюники**), which may have led to **глюк** by further reduction.

Comment: @mustaccio Also **галюны**.

Comment: Out of curiosity: are there good references to support the usage among Russian hippies and the evolution from галлюцинация to приглючилось, глючный, глючить, and глюк?

Answer (score 0):

Единственное что приходит на ум - это то, что слово это пришло к нам от немецких травокуров, которые словом glück, помимо традиционного значения, называли также как сам приход после употребления своих препаратов, так и все его сопутствующие эффекты. В IT-среду, соответственно, слово пришло уже от туда. И хотя на 100% точно это, разумеется, сказать нынче едва ли возможно, но если это так, то тогда понятно почему об этом не напишут в словарях...

Comment: можешь-ли ты как-то обосновать связь с немецким словом *Glück*?

Comment: [Маловероятно](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/63214)

Comment: Я просто чую по общему характеру. Похоже на то, что слово это появилось недавно, и что должно быть оно, упрощенное звучание какого-нибудь модного иностранного слова из ближайшего зарубежья. Звучит оно как-то уж больно в стиле порождений тусовок конца 70-х или времен 80-х. И похожих по звучанию слов в других языках из стран бывшего соцлагеря кроме немецкого я просто не знаю. Разумеется, если бы я был хоть насколько-то в этом уверен, тем более - если мог бы четко обосновать, то изначально так бы и написал. Но, к счастью, я не настолько стар.